# Как сделать маску для панели во время загрузки в ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Здравствуйте.
Работаю с `ExtJS 3.1`. При исполнении JS-кода, допустим:

```
... .... .... ...
thisWindow.close();
Data.loadHtmlForm();// Берем с сервера некоторые данные
openNextWindow();// открыть следующее окно, в котором должны быть загруженные данные.
```

Закрывается текущее окно, затем следует `Ajax`-запрос, который длится некоторое время. Проблема состоит в том, что пока выполняется `Ajax`-запрос, продолжают исполняться следующие функции.

Вопрос: **Как** приостановить дальнейшее исполнение кода до того времени, пока не завершится запрос к серверу? Или как мне сделать маску для панели во время загрузки? Тут, функция `Data.loadHtmlForm()` загружает с сервера данные и инициализирует ими переменную `htmlBlank`. Привожу код моей панели:

```
xtype   : 'panel',
html    :   htmlBlank,
x       : 0,
y       : 0,
width   : 600,
height  : 850,
id      : 'panelId'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смысл в том, что если мы грузим в грид инфу из БД, а пока она грузится отображать кул-хацкер "Loading...", то мы можем использовать маску, привязав ее изначально к загрузке Store:

var companies = new Ext.data.Store({
reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
fields: [
'user_id',
'user_login',
'user_profile_name',
],
root: 'rows'
}),
proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
url: 'урл который грузит компании из БД/companies.php'
}),
autoLoad: false
});

Изначально autoLoad ставим в значение false, а затем после подключения маски уже грузим companies.load(); Маска становится связанной с хранилищем companies:

var card = Ext.get('cardID');
var mask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.get('cardID'), {msg:"Загрузка данных...", store:companies});
companies.load();

cardID - это идентификатор таба в гриде:
var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
бла бла ...
items: [{
title: 'Карточки',
xtype: 'editorgrid',
id: 'cardID',
clickstoEdit: 1,
store: companies,
colModel: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
бла бла ...